# DateTime Format Strings?

Tags: vb.net, datetime, string-formatting

I have the date format string dd-mm-yy. Please can you tell me how to add hours and minutes to the string (i.e 13-03-2010.21.03) ....

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-mm-yy") ?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

please check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx and http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/ for more information

```
String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", datetime)
```

Comment: He wants 2-digit day, month, and he doesn't want seconds.

Answer (score 5):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy.HH.mm")
```

Change the Today to Now

Please note that mm = minutes and MM = months

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy.hh.mm")
```

If you want 24 hours:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy.HH.mm")
```

See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) documentation.

Note that the format string you first used is incorrect, as `mm` stands for minutes so you should have used `MM` for months.

You are also using `Today`, which does not have the time component (so it would always be 00:00:00). If you need those (hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds), you should use `Now`.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen - And he was asking for minutes to be added. Answer amended.

Comment: i wasn't the one behind the d/v so i can't answer, i guess, but for one thing, `Today` will always yield `00.00`

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy.HH.mm");
```

`mm` is minutes, `MM` is months, so your current example is wrong.

Also, note that you need to use `Now` rather than `Today`, otherwise it'll always be `00.00`

Comment: It looks like he also wants 4-digit year (yyyy), despite his current code.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy.HH.mm");
```

MM for Months
mm for minutes